# how to get tcp client ip and port in c# and show that?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I want to get tcp client ip address and port but I can't to do that.I want to use socket in my code except tcp listener class and my goal is get client ip and port without  this class. below is my code:(I want to get client ip address and port before if(rc){} condition)

```
 namespace Example
{
public partial class TCP_Server : Form
{
    Socket socketServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Socket socketClient = null;
    public TCP_Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void start()
    {

        IPEndPoint ipens = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txt_ip.Text), int.Parse(txt_port.Text));
        socketServer.Bind(ipens);
        MessageBox.Show("wait");
        while (true)
        {
            socketServer.Listen(2);
            socketClient = socketServer.Accept();

            MessageBox.Show("accept");
            Thread trgetmsg = new Thread(new ThreadStart(getmsg));
            trgetmsg.Start();
        }
    }

    public void getmsg()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string[] barray2 = new string[10];
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] barray = new byte[1024];
                EndPoint iprec = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4040);
                int rc = socketClient.ReceiveFrom(barray , ref iprec);
                barray2[counter] = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(barray, 0, rc);
                counter =counter+1;

                if (rc > 0)
                {
                     MessageBox.Show(iprec.);
                    if (barray2[0] == barray2[1])
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("client: " + Encoding.Unicode.GetString(barray, 0, rc));
                        socketClient.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(barray2[0])); 
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        catch { ;}


    }
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This will provide endpoint info of accepted client;

```
socketClient = socketServer.Accept();
var endPoint = (IPEndPoint)socketClient.RemoteEndPoint;
```